# clojure.test unable to resolve symbol from `eval`. Works in REPL and lein run

Tags: testing, clojure, eval

Please bear with this contrived example but it was the simplest thing I could think of to recreate the issue.

```
(ns something.core)

(defn call-foo [something & args]
  (let [a-foo (:foo (eval (:quux something)))]
    (apply a-foo args)))

(def Something {
  :foo (fn [& args] args)
  :bar (fn [something] (call-foo something))
})

(defn make-something []
  {:quux 'Something})
```

Running the following in the REPL or with `lein run` works well.

```
(let [subject (make-something)                      
      actual (call-foo subject "hello" "greetings")]
  (println actual))                                 
;;=> (hello greetings)
```

The problem occurs only during this test and executing `lein test`:

```
(ns something.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [something.core :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (let [subject (make-something)
        actual  (call-foo subject "hello" "greetings")]
    (is (= ["hello" "greetings"] actual))))
```

This throws an error. An example output:

```
ERROR in (a-test) (Compiler.java:6464)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: Something in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/0n/c7q7860j34xfc2r1x4q51jrh0000gn/T/form-init9215140948330409114.clj:1:6436)
```

The line "Unable to resolve symbol: Something in this context" makes me think `Something` is not in context for some reason while I `eval` in `call-foo`. But why is this the case only in the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `eval` does not see context. Your `'Something` resolves in `something.core` and `something.core-test` since you have refered all. It won't resolve from whatever namespace where `lein test` runs its tests.

To fix the immediate problem change

```
'Something
```

to

```
`Something
```

so that it is namespace-qualified. The test will then run (and fail), but that's another issue (`println` returns `nil` for one thing).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me. Didn't know about qualifying the namespace with the backtick. I'll fix the example also so `:foo` returns the vector of args rather than calling `println`.